# Android button suggestion

Tags: android

Can some one suggest me what type of button , or other type of view should I use in horizontal scroll view to on off buttons like this in fox application.

When user click on button, current button should be with pressed state, and others in normal state.

[image: android fox news app]

thanks

Comment: You'll need to implement your own view if you are going for this exact look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the layout is like the above, a tabbed layout is the way to go

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

EDIT: sorry didn't realize you only wanted to refer to the lower part.

You could use  radiobuttons and put them all in a radiogroup

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

Comment: I'm not talking for tabs. please see red square

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Gallery view to have the look like that. There are some bugs with gallery view where you can't recycle and reuse a view, but otherwise that will give the effect you are looking for.